# typo3 image processing test fails

Tags: image-processing, typo3

I wanted to start learning typo3 and for that reason I installed typo3 on a local apache to practise. But if I use the testmenu from the install tool, I got errors from creating every file format except `.GIF` and `.BMP`. 
I tried some other configurations of Graphics Magick but the reason was the same. Then I read, that maybe the problem is the disabled `exec` function. 
Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

thx

**edit: the problem were missing library delegates of GraphicsMagick**

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick requires the `exec()` function. There is currently no way to use an alternate way. So you need to change your provider.

Comment: @SPie says, that it is his local installation, so it is not provider, but local **php.ini** line `disable_functions` shouldn't contain `exec` inside.

Comment: Oh, my fault, missed that part.

Comment: the `disable_functions` line contained `pcntl_exec`. I removed it, but nothing happened. Is there something else I have to do to re-enable `exec`?

Comment: Whats your enviroment? Windows, Linux?

Comment: @SPie, also what Install Tool tells you in _Basic Info_ section - can it find GrapgicsMagic binary?

Comment: @Merec, I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, apache2.2.22, php5.4.6, GraphicsMagick1.3.18    
@ViktorLivakivskyi, yes it can. Only warning I got, was that some functions are disabled. I tried to remove the `disabled_functions` line from the php.ini...now the warning disappeared, but the errors didn't.